# How I can modify a property value of collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My collection:

```
 ($usersWithCommission) Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2625
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "userId" => 1
      "name" => "Sim Aufderhar"
      "net_commission" => null
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "userId" => 2
      "name" => "Carolyn Lang III"
      "net_commission" => null
    ]
  ]
}
```

I would like modify the net_commission property, but I can not:

```
foreach ($soldProperties as $property) {
            if (!$property->buyer_user_id && !$property->seller_transferring_user_id) {
                $usersWithCommission->where('userId', $property->user_id)->first()['net_commission'] += $property->net_commission_of_sold;
            }
        }
```

How I can?
Thanks your answers.

Comment: How do you want to modify it? What could be your desired output? Do your collection element contains the  `net_commission_of_sold` attribute?

Comment: Loop the collection and modify it?

Comment: No. I loop a collection, and modify an other collection property.

Comment: @LaszloP I get that, but in order to modify the element of the collection is it enough with the actual data of the element (like a computed property) or do you do another operations/get data from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function test()
{
    $collection = [
        [ "userId" => 1, "name" => "Sim Aufderhar", "net_commission" => null ],
        [ "userId" => 2, "name" => "Carolyn Lang III", "net_commission" => null ],
     ];
      $data= collect($collection)->map(function($collection, $key) {
       $collect = (object)$collection;
       return [
            'userId' => $collect->userId,
            'name' => $collect->name,
            'net_commission' => $this->modify_commision($key)
       ];
   });

  dd($data);
}

public function modify_commision($key) {
    $property = [
        ['userId' => 1 ,'net_commission_of_sold' => 30],
        ['user_id' => 2,'net_commission_of_sold' => 40]
    ];
    return $property[$key]['net_commission_of_sold'];
 }

 ***Hope it helps you***
```

Comment: In laravel 8.x use [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-transform) , Unlike most other collection methods, transform modifies the collection itself. If you wish to create a new collection instead, use the map method.

Answer (score 5):

Collections provide a method `map` which allows you to iterate your collection and add/modify fields.

```
function modify_net_commision($var) {
   return YOUR_LOGIC_HERE;
}

$collection = [
   [ "userId" => 1, "name" => "Sim Aufderhar", "net_commission" => null ],
   [ "userId" => 2, "name" => "Carolyn Lang III", "net_commission" => null ],
];

$external_var = 'I will be used on modify_net_commision function';

$new_collection = collect($collection)->map(function ($arr) use ($external_var) {
    $arr['net_commission'] = modify_net_commision($external_var);
    return $arr;
})
```

If you want to remove some fields from your collection, use `reject` method.

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Hope it helps you.

Have a great day.